Why did Nazi Bishop François Auvity escape all punishment, both criminal and ecclesiastical, after the Liberation of France?
Why did Nazi Bishop François Auvity escape all punishment, both criminal and ecclesiastical, after the Liberation of France by the Allies, and how could his criminal role remain hushed up for EIGHTY long years ??

From reading blog post doing the rounds https://medium.com/@schlomohanukkaev/monseigneur-auvity-le-collabo-antis%C3%A9mite-et-lacad%C3%A9mie-fran%C3%A7aise-historiette-d-un-criminel-de-a93205498af6 he seems to have encouraged anti Semiticism, encouraged working for Germany, and denounced the resistance, which is all bad but not as far as I can see criminal. But there's a lot of angry flowery language in that piece, I might have missed an important fact. I agree it is disappointing - but not astonishing - the church didn't punish him more.

Please document your preliminary research

Auvity did not escape all punishment. He was removed from his role as a Bishop.

Would you detail what, exactly, you would want to trial him for? That would make this question approach being answerable.

Your premise is faulty. Auvity's resignation was accepted by Pius XII in November 1945. That's a rather severe ecclesiastical punishment.
As noted in Time magazine of NOVEMBER 19, 1945:

Msgr. Francois Auvity, Bishop of Mende. He recently apologized in a pastoral letter for having advised French youths to accept forced labor in Germany.


The position of the Vatican on collaborationist clergymen was not clearly defined. Official feeling was embodied in an age-old, unwritten law of the Church that its prelates, like Caesar’s wife, must be above suspicion. The law is, in effect: any prelate whose personal conduct, past or present, gives rise to discussion or dissension which might reflect unfavorably on the Church must feel duty-bound—guilty or not—to renounce his dignity to prevent adverse discussion of the Church.


Bishop Dutoit and Auvity evidently felt duty-bound to resign from their dioceses. Last week, Pipe Pius XII accepted both resignations.


I think its fair to say that recent history has shown The Catholic Church considers reassigning problematic clergy to be a much harsher punishment than its laity does.
